# How to create a search functionality that searches for ingredients when the user searches for a meal?

Tags: django

I am trying to create a project in Django which allows users to see a list of images of the ingredients when they search for a particular meal, but I am not sure how I would start this project.

I can see that there are some apis available, however, I intend to create this from scratch.

For example, if the user enters lasagne the images displayed will be the ingredients of lasagne so the pastry, minced meat etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a search engine such as Elasticsearch which will index your data and give you an optimized search solution.

If you don't intend on using a search engine, you can have a look at Field lookups (such as exact, contains, etc)in django which help you find model objects on the basis of the text you type in

Link of django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups

Comment: Thank you for the reply, how will I use this search engine that will provide me with the ingredients of when a user enters a meal. For example, if the user enters lasagne the images displayed will be the ingredients of lasagne so the pastry, minced meat etc...

Comment: You can run the elasticsearch server and then use a wrapper (such as Haystack, elasticsearch_dsl, etc) to communicate with it. In your model, the field that will contain the name of the meal can then be indexed. Then you can get the results using Elasticsearch, and the associated image as well (for the meals returned by your search engine). Documentation of Haystack: https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html

Comment: That's great thanks, however where would I get the data from for all the ingredients and the meals?